# Search for online solutions disabled on windows 10 pro 64bit

Tags: windows-10, control-panel

Because of some recent occurring freeze, I wanted to investigate on the cause, and tried to "search for online solutions", but I got an error saying that the function is disabled.

I searched online, but all I could find explains how to disable such service, while I'd want to enable it...

When I access the config screen I see this:

[image: Solutions center]

Now, the language is Italian, but you might notice that all four options are greyed out, as is the option to "modify settings for all users".

I also tried opening the control panel "as an administrator", but to no avail.

The related service seems to be running though, with a start type of "automatic (trigger)".

How can I get it back working?

**EDIT:**

I tried creating another administrator account, and THAT account has this function active... Now, if I could get to the same screen, and click on the "change settings for all users" option, it'd be done, but I do not know how to get to that window on the other account!

Comment: Is this your personal computer, or a work-provided computer?

Comment: This is my personal computer

Comment: Are you logged in with an Administrator account? Have you run any "Stop-Windows-10-Spying" type utilities (like O&O ShutUp10)?

Comment: Yes, I am logged in with an admin account, and no, I never had any similar tool installed.

Comment: Are you by chance logged in as the built-in `Administrator` account?

Comment: No, I have my own account.

Comment: By the way, is the Administrator account visible from the user list ... ? I see only myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I've found a solution to this.

To correct the problem, I opened a Powershell as administrator and then used the command [`Enable-WindowsErrorReporting`](https://technet.microsoft.com/it-it/library/jj590828(v=wps.630).aspx).

I now see it enabled, I'll try to figure out how to properly configure it.